# Creating a SQL Query where job ran 4 times unsucessfully then completed and to show all runs of that job

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

My task is to create a SQL query that if, for example, a job ran 4 times unsuccessfully but worked or was forced complete on the 5th run there should be 5 entries for it. So far I am able to get only the failed jobs, however, i want it to show all runs of a single job until it completes. Is this possible to do with SQL itself?

Ex:

```
JOB1        FAILED
JOB1        FAILED
JOB1        FAILED
JOB1        FAILED
JOB1        COMPLETED
```

Comment: Are you asking about querying a table which contains job name and completion status, or are you trying to capture the results of an actual database administration task? Regardless, some more information would be helpful.

Comment: @KentWeigel I am trying to capture the results of an actual database administration task.